# How to uncheck "safe update" when getting revision in P4V?

Tags: p4v

The underlined option; its check-box is grayed out.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The logic is based on the options you have set on your workspace. When your workspace is set to 'allwrite' and 'noclobber' the server is going to do the safe check regardless of what flags you set on sync, so we indicate that by disabling and checking the checkbox. I should add a tooltip to it as well explaining that to make it clearer.

Comment: "Clobber: overwrite writeable workspace files when getting revisions" 
I had this unchecked since I don't *always* want to overwrite files when getting revisions, but I want the option to do so on a per fetch basis. So maybe that checkbox shouldn't be grayed out?

Comment: No no, that's correct, if you have "clobber" unchecked, then your client is set to "noclobber".